# D programming incomplete compiler

Tags: compiler-errors, d

I'm trying to pick up the D programming language, and I downloaded the compiler from the official site (http://www.digitalmars.com/d/download.html). and I'm following the original D programming tutorials and book.
But the compiler doesn't seem to recognize a lot of keywords, for example when I try to use the "immutable" keyword the compiler raises the "Error: undefined identifier immutable" error. And it does this with a lot of other features of D.

How is this possible? It is in fact the official compiler as far as I know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You downloaded the D1 compiler. Get the D2 one.

Comment: im pretty sure i downloaded the D2 one. but reinstalling it right now and disabeling the D1 option.

Comment: ah, thanks it works now. apperently it automatically selected the D1 version of the compiler (which was installed as well)

Answer (score 6):

You're probably trying to use D2 code with D1 compiler.

Comment: ah, thanks it works now. apperently it automatically selected the D1 version of the compiler (which was installed as well)